# Can't add product to Shopify via Ruby code but can through rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I have the following code

```
shopify_store_name = ShopifyStore.where(:store_id => 98).pluck('shop').first
shopify_access_token = ShopifyStore.where(:store_id => 98).pluck('access_token').first
session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new("#{shopify_store_name}.myshopify.com", shopify_access_token)
ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session)
shop = ShopifyAPI::Shop.current

# Create a new product
new_product = ShopifyAPI::Product.new
new_product.title = 'This is a new Product'
new_product.product_type = 'Type'
new_product.vendor = 'Vendor'
new_product.save
```

Which when run causes : Failed. Response code = 403. Response message = Forbidden.

However if I copy and paste the code in to my rails console window it works perfectly?  Any one got any idea what that would be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

403 will usually happen for permission issues.

You probably don't have the permission `write_products` for that token.

Comment: That was my first thought too.  But the token works perfectly to write_products when executed from a console.  Same token .. Also I re-created the token with the following permissions:api_scope  = 'write_products,write_content,write_themes,write_customers,write_orders,write_script_tags,write_shipping'

Answer (score 0):

For those getting this error, you need to set up the permission in your shopify_app.rb initializer (in the initializers folder under config) under the scope field:

```
ShopifyApp.configure do |config|
  config.application_name = "My Shopify App"
  config.api_key = ENV['SHOPIFY_API_KEY']
  config.secret = ENV['SHOPIFY_API_SECRET']
  config.old_secret = ""
  config.scope = "read_products,read_customers" # Consult this page for more scope options:
                                 # https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth/scopes
  config.reauth_on_access_scope_changes = true
  config.embedded_app = true
  config.after_authenticate_job = false
  config.api_version = "2020-04"
  config.shop_session_repository = 'Shop'
  config.allow_jwt_authentication = true
  config.webhooks = [
    {topic: 'app/uninstalled', address: "#{ENV['APP_URL']}/webhooks/app_uninstalled", format: 'json'},
  ]
end
```